# NgModule routing Angular2 with 2.0.0-rc.5 showing error Unhandled promise rejection Error: Cannot match any routes: ''(…)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am using NgModule in angular2, 2.0.0-rc.5 but I got the error shim.js:4035 Unhandled promise rejection Error: Cannot match any routes: ''(…). How can I resolve this error.Please help me here is my code.

### app/base/app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### app/base/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { EventService } from '../shared/service/event-service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'owb-workbench-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [EventService],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
 })

export class AppComponent {
}
```

### app/base/app.module.ts

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule, APP_BASE_HREF} from "@angular/common";
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms/index';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '../shared/http/base.http';
import { EventService } from '../shared/service/event-service';

import { routing } from './app.routes';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component'
import { appRoutingProviders } from './app.routes'
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { NKDatetime } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';

@NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,HttpModule,CommonModule,routing,appRoutingProviders],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, NKDatetime,DashboardComponent],
      exports: [NKDatetime],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
      providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
                  { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' },
                  HTTP_PROVIDERS,EventService,HttpClient]
    })
    export class AppModule { 
    }
```

app/base/app.routes.ts

```
    import { provideRouter, RouterConfig,RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
    import { DashboardRoutes } from '../dashboard/index';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    ...DashboardRoutes
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

### app/base/main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

### app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html

```
<h1>Hello World Welcome</h1>
```

### app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { TopNavComponent } from '../shared/topnav/topnav';
import { SidebarComponent } from '../shared/sidebar/sidebar';
import { RightNavComponent } from '../shared/rightnav/rightnav';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'dashboard-app',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, TopNavComponent, SidebarComponent, RightNavComponent ]
})

export class DashboardComponent {}
```

### app/dashboard/dashboard.routes.ts

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './index';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GridViewComponent } from './+gridview/gridview.component'

 const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
      path: 'dashboard', 
      component: DashboardComponent
  }

];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

### app/dashboard/index.ts

/**
 * This barrel file provides the export for the lazy loaded DashboardComponent.
 */

```
export * from './dashboard.component';
export * from './dashboard.routes';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import your routes into the app.module.ts like this.  I believe you also need to provide an empty route. In this case, home is my default route, you would change it to be dashboard if that's what your default is.

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'  },
    { path: 'home',  loadChildren: './app/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
```

My app.module.ts (notice the RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) import):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), SharedModule.forRoot() ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [ appRoutingProviders ]

}) 

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Hi John,Could you exaplain more.I have a file "app.route.ts" could you explain how to integrate your code in my file.

Comment: Hi John,Could you tell me which file I need to import for appRoutingProviders

Comment: Hi John,I made all the changes according to you.I got the error.Unhandled promise rejection Error: Cannot match any routes: ''(…)

Comment: Post your code now, so we can look at the changes you made.

Comment: You're still using ...dashboard.  I couldn't get that to work.  follow my example and see, it works for me.

Comment: Hi John,I am agree with your answer.Now it is working for me.I have one more question.Could you tell me how to use this in case of RouterModule.forChild.I want to add clild to my dashboard